# Closing streams on exception - OK to assume where exceptions can happen?

Tags: java, exception, io

This is more of a style and nitpick question, but I'm curious about opinions on this. Consider the following code (and ignore that I could use a different function to avoid the issue):

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(new FileInputStream(f1), f2);
```

`copyInputStreamToFile` is from apache.commons.io and will close the stream. I reason that this should close the InputStream in all usual situations, because if an exception happens when creating the `InputStream` there is nothing to close, and if one happens inside `copyInputStreamToFile` then this function will close the stream for me.

However, is it really safe to assume there can be no exception or error between the creation of the `InputStream` and the start of the try-block in `copyInputStreamToFile`? I'm thinking of unusual things like `OutOfMemoryError` or `ThreadDeath`. So, we could rewrite the code above as:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(f1);
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, f2);
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

That should be safe, but do you think it is necessary?

Comment: No solution helps against `ThreadDeath` and OOME won't happen out of the blue -- it can only be thrown from code that requests memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends if your application is concurrent or not. If it is, you can not assume that between the creation of the **InputStream** and the body of **copyInputStreamToFile** no other code will run.

**Marko Topolnik** answers the case when the application is not concurrent.